# Checking presence of fields in form which don't exist in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, error-handling, custom-errors

My Server model:
   json_field

I have some multiple fields in my create form and I store them as one json(blod) field in my Server model. 
So, I cannot use:

```
validates_presence_of :json_field, :message => "can't be blank"
```

Imagine this is my view:

```
= simple_form_for(@server, :html => one_submit_only(:server), :remote => true) do |f|
  = link_to_close "servers/new"
  = f.error_messages :object_name => t('server')

  %input{:type=>"text", :name=>"page_title"}
  %input{:type=>"text", :name=>"page_body"}
```

How could I show the error message when one of those fields(page_title or page_body) in the form is blank?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just check the fields as they appear in the form:

```
validates :page_title, :page_body, presence: true
```